# Masonry square grid

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Does anyone know how to make this http://cl.ly/image/1A3u173Z2H3G/masonry.jpg ? I've tried plugins like isotope or masonry but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by div or table

in diagram below i those box are div ... to make bottom design you just need to change position or yellow div to green div that  it

[image]

Comment: Your rather dapper hat appears to be a little loose fitting, good sir!